# How to simplify python function?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I would like to ask if anyone could help me with simplification of code given below.

Function `save_session()` creates dictionary with nested dictionaries that are dumped to .json file later. Data example shown below code of function.

I am aware that it doesn't look good and I am almost sure that there is nicer way to get the same result. I will be grateful for any advice or tips.

```py
def save_session():
    """Exports current data to .json file."""
    data_to_save = {}

    # add workout plans
    for workout in workouts_instances:
        data_to_save[workout.name] = {}

        # add trainings
        if workout.trainings:
            data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"] = {}

            for training in workout.trainings:
                data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name] = {}

                # add training exercises
                if training.exercises:
                    data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name]['exercises'] = {
                        exercise.name: {} for exercise in training.exercises
                    }

                    for exercise in training.exercises:

                        if exercise.details:
                            data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name]['exercises'][exercise.name][
                                'details'] = {detail: value for detail, value in
                                              exercise.details.items()}

        # add exercises
        if workout.exercises:
            data_to_save[workout.name]["exercises"] = {}

            exercises_to_save = data_to_save[workout.name]["exercises"]

            for exercise in workout.exercises:
                exercises_to_save[exercise.name] = {}

                if exercise.details:
                    details = exercise.details
                    exercises_to_save[exercise.name]['details'] = {detail: value for detail, value in details.items()}
```

```
{
    "FBV - Full Body Workout": {
        "description": "short decription",
        "trainings": {
          "Training A": {
            "exercises": {
              "squats": {
                "details": {
                  "description": "squats with barbell",
                  "series": 4,
                  "repeats": 4
                  "load": 70
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "exercises": {
            "some exercise name": {
                "details": {
                    "description": "some description",
                    "series": 5,
                    "repeats": 5,
                    "load": 60
                }
            },
            "bench press - wide": {
                "details": {
                    "description": "bench press with wide grip",
                    "series": 5,
                    "repeats": 5,
                    "load": 60
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is going to be the best place for this

Comment: do you have a specific problem or are you looking to improve working code?#

Comment: Read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic before posting there, though.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: It works and I try to improve that code.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a redundant bit.

```py
data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name]['exercises'][exercise.name][
                                'details'] = {detail: value for detail, value in
                                              exercise.details.items()}
```

It is the same with

```py
 data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"][training.name]['exercises'][exercise.name]['details'] = exercise.details
```

Same

```py
exercises_to_save[exercise.name]['details'] = {detail: value for detail, value in details.items()}
```

Which can be written as

```py
exercises_to_save[exercise.name]['details'] = details
```

I have assumed that `details` is in fact a `dict` from reading the `items()` method invoked on it.

If that is correct, it is possible to write a more tense but still readable function using dictionary comprehension. You could even do away with the `data_to_save` name and return a dictionary composed all from dictionary comprehension expression but I find that to be less readable.

```py
def save_session():
    """Exports current data to .json file."""
    data_to_save = defaultdict(dict)

    # add workout plans
    for workout in workouts_instances:
        # add trainings
        if workout.trainings:
            data_to_save[workout.name]["trainings"] = {
                training.name: {
                    'exercises': {
                        exercise.name: exercise.details
                        for exercise in training.exercises
                        if exercise.details
                    }
                } if training.exercises else {}
                for training in workout.trainings
            }
        # add exercises
        if workout.exercises:
            data_to_save[workout.name]['exercises'] = {
                exercise.name: {
                    'details': exercise.details
                }
                if exercise.details else {}
                for exercise in workout.exercises
            }
```